# Login Screen Always Shown

Tags: swift, nsuserdefaults

I have a login screen that prompts the user to login. After successful login the first time, I need the app to eliminate the login screen when the user opens the app again. I am using NSUserDefaults to set the successful login as true. However, the login screen is always shown to the user. Please help. Thanks.

```
override func viewDidLoad() {
    super.viewDidLoad()
    // Do any additional setup after loading the view, typically from a nib.



    if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().objectForKey("onoroff") != nil)  {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)


    }



}

override func didReceiveMemoryWarning() {
    super.didReceiveMemoryWarning()
    // Dispose of any resources that can be recreated.
}


@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

    if ((loginid.text == "Hussain") && (passwordText.text == "1234" ))
    {
            NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "onoroff")

            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)        }
    else
    {
    failedtext.hidden = false       }


}
```

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try adding

```
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("onoroff")))  {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)
}
```

in viewDidAppear method instead of viewDidLoad

Comment: Thanks a lot. It is working now very well. You saved my time. I really appreciate your help.

Answer (score 0):

Change objectForKey to boolForKey

```
if (NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().boolForKey("onoroff"))  {
    self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)


    }
```

Also do this

```
@IBAction func button(sender: AnyObject) {

    if ((loginid.text == "Hussain") && (passwordText.text == "1234" ))
    {
           NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().setBool(true, forKey: "onoroff")
           NSUserDefaults.standardUserDefaults().synchronize()


            self.performSegueWithIdentifier("segue", sender: nil)  
     }
    else
    {
           failedtext.hidden = false       
     }


}
```